# How declare two prompt variables for hosts in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

How declare two prompt variables for hosts in ansible playbook, I tried below Playbook but without luck.
............................................................................................................................................................
Thank you in advance.

```
---
- name: MD5 File Check 
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: "{{ cluster_host_1 }}", "{{cluster_host_2 }}" 
  hosts: localhost
  remote_user: sv_operator
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "file_1"
      prompt: "File name"
      private: no
    - name: "cluster_host_1"
      prompt: "Enter 1st Host name"
      private: no
    - name: "cluster_host_2"
      prompt: "Enter 2nd Host Name"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "/tmp/{{ file_1 }}"
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: output
      delegate_to: "{{ cluster_host_1 }}" 
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output.stat.checksum }}"
    - stat:
        path: "/tmp/{{ file_2 }}"
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: output_
      delegate_to: "{{ cluster_host_2 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output_.stat.checksum }}"
```

Comment: You should have seen the warning: "... found a duplicate dict key (hosts). Using last defined value only." Is this what you want?

Comment: No, I need my user enter two hosts manually for ansible-play, I don't need it with fix way.

Comment: See [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where does the variable `file_2` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the remote hosts and /tmp/file1

```sh
shell> ssh admin@test_01 sha256 /tmp/file1
SHA256 (/tmp/file1) = e2611a1fac7fc2ab99d2e792ad84f34e66740d6a3d77b97b4da39a3758357da0

shell> ssh admin@test_02 sha256 /tmp/file1
SHA256 (/tmp/file1) = 109f60103192b5c8f4e33c26b4f9c7b94489bf8de0325497b7f5a0668dc1a402
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: SHA256 File Check 
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "file_1"
      prompt: "File name"
      private: no
    - name: "cluster_host_1"
      prompt: "Enter 1st Host name"
      private: no
    - name: "cluster_host_2"
      prompt: "Enter 2nd Host Name"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "/tmp/{{ file_1 }}"
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: output
      delegate_to: "{{ cluster_host_1 }}" 
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output.stat.checksum }}"
    - stat:
        path: "/tmp/{{ file_1 }}"
        checksum_algorithm: sha256
      register: output_
      delegate_to: "{{ cluster_host_2 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ output_.stat.checksum }}"
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
File name: file1
Enter 1st Host name: test_01
Enter 2nd Host Name: test_02

PLAY [SHA256 File Check] ****

TASK [stat] ****
ok: [localhost -> test_01]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: e2611a1fac7fc2ab99d2e792ad84f34e66740d6a3d77b97b4da39a3758357da0

TASK [stat] ****
ok: [localhost -> test_02]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 109f60103192b5c8f4e33c26b4f9c7b94489bf8de0325497b7f5a0668dc1a402

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=4 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your play to run on two hosts, declared through variables. You have two options.

**Option 1:**

Since your target hosts are comma separated, you might as well input them that way.

```yaml
- hosts: '{{ my_hosts }}'
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: 'sv_operator'

  vars_prompt:
    - name: 'my_hosts'
      prompt: 'Comma separated list of hosts'
      private: no
```

Then when prompted:

```
Comma separated list of hosts: host1.local,host2.local
```

**Option 2:**

Capture each host in individual variable like `host_1` and `host_2`, then call it as a list in a play.

```yaml
- hosts:
    - '{{ host_1 }}'
    - '{{ host_2 }}'
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: 'sv_operator'

  vars_prompt:
    - name: 'host_1'
      prompt: 'First host'
      private: no
    - name: 'host_2'
      prompt: 'Second host'
      private: no
```

Then when prompted:

```
First host: host1.local
Second host: host2.local
```

Comment: it work also with me, I appreciate your help so much.